# What happens when the server is in an infinite loop and the client stops?

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how the "talking" between the server and the client is done.

So, when the server is generating an infinite loop, `echo`ing`"hello<br />"`, for example, what happens when the client stops, or hits 'back'?

How does the server know it's the end of the loop or does it take an endless process by its side?

Is there anywhere I can read about it just to get the big picture?

Comment: theoretically, the server doesn't stop until the execution time reaches the request timeout value (or some runtime, stack overflow, out of memory etc error)

Comment: by endlessly echoing, why should it ever reach any error or limitation ?

Comment: it would eventually reach the request timeout limit

Comment: who sets this timeout ? is that a client request, is that a server setting?

Comment: On request, Apache has an endpoint (client) it talks to via TCP/IP protocol (HTTP in this case, is built on top of TCP/IP protocol). Once the client connects, Apache launches a PHP process in one of its client threads. That thread then does the job and when it's done executing (it's signaled by PHP process that work is done), it returns the response to the client. If we're talking about endless loop, then either the server crashes (due to RAM exhaustion) or the process gets terminated in case certain variables are set (max_execution_time and similar).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The client (browser) has a [TCP/IP session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Network_function) established with your server, waiting for the HTTP response of your website. When the user hits back/cancel/close, this TCP connection is closed immediately by the client.

The webserver (i.e. apache) will inform the PHP interpreter of the [TCP *connection close*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination).

Unless the `php.ini` directive [`ignore_user_abort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort) is set to `1` (on server side, `0` is PHP default), the PHP interpreter will then abort script execution when the current atomic operation finishes (in your example: `echo()`)

However, even when you set [`ignore_user_abort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort) explicitly to `1` you will hit PHPs [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) or the apache [`TimeOut`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#timeout) (both are configurable on server side, too)

also see [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) and [`set_time_limit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Answer (score 0):

Even if your php script has an infinite loop, php.ini has a `max_execution_time` which will kill the process if the time exceeds.

I am not sure how it will work when the client closes a connection. Apache might kill the process but I don't think PHP will be notified of the client's connection closing.

Answer (score -1):

If you do `set_time_limit(0);` in the script (so the PHP interpreter lets it run forever), then the script will probably run until the web server kills it after however long the `TimeOut` variable is set to (defaults to 300 seconds I think, and as far as I know is only an Apache setting).

See [Apache's docs for the TimeOut directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#timeout).

Comment: Where is the *TimeOut* variable set, and who sets it ?

Comment: @Ted: In httpd.conf, apache2.conf, or apache.conf, depending on your OS.  Whoever administers the actual web server settings would be the one to set the value, and I think it's solely a server-level variable (meaning you probably can't change it at the virtual host level).  I've updated my answer with a link.